Webpack Module Federation shared dependencies with eager attribute
I have a couple of questions regarding shared dependencies with Webpack Module Federation

If we use eager: true for a dependency, does it mean that the code for that dependency is included within the remoteEntry.js that gets downloaded to the browser ? Also, is it applicable to both the Host and the Remote ? OR does remoteEntry.js always contains metadata info and never the actual code ?

If we have a host that shares dep-a at version 1.0.0. When the host loads up, it will put dep-a:1.0.0 into the shared context. If the remote also shares dep-a:1.0.0 it will not put it in the context, because it is already there. If the host was sharing dep-a:1.0.1, then the context will now have two versions: the dep-a:1.0.0 from the host and dep-a:1.0.1 from the remote.
Is the above statement correct ?


